# Using concepts with multiple parameters as constraints to functions

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Define a scalar to be any arithmetic type:

```cpp
template<class T>
concept scalar = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;
```

A vector `T` of a scalar `ScalarType` satisfies the following:

```cpp
template<class T, class ScalarType>
concept vector = std::equality_comparable<T> && scalar<ScalarType> && requires(T a, T b, ScalarType c)
{
    {a + b} -> std::same_as<T>;
    {a - b} -> std::same_as<T>;
    {a += b} -> std::same_as<T&>;
    {a -= b} -> std::same_as<T&>;
    {c * a} -> std::same_as<T>;
    {a * c} -> std::same_as<T>;
    {a / c} -> std::same_as<T>;
    {a *= c} -> std::same_as<T&>;
    {a /= c} -> std::same_as<T&>;
    {-a} -> std::same_as<T>;
    {zero(std::declval<empty<T>>())} -> std::same_as<T>;
};
```

A point satisfies the following:

```cpp
template<class T, class VectorType, class ScalarType>
concept point = std::equality_comparable<T>
    && vector<VectorType, ScalarType>
    && requires(T p1, T p2, VectorType v)
{
    {p1 + v} -> std::same_as<T>;
    {p1 - v} -> std::same_as<T>;
    {p1 += v} -> std::same_as<T&>;
    {p1 -= v} -> std::same_as<T&>;
    {p1 - p2} -> std::same_as<VectorType>;
};
```

Now I want to apply `point` as a constraint to a function that computes the distance between two points:

```cpp
template<class Vector, class Scalar, point<Vector, Scalar> P>
constexpr auto distance(P p1, P p2)
{
    return norm(p1 - p2);
}
```

But it is not possible to deduce Vector and Scalar given only P. First notice that

```cpp
static_assert(point<int*, intptr_t, intptr_t>);
```

Any (non-void) pointer is a point with intptr_t as both its vector and scalar.

Trying this:

```cpp
constexpr std::array<int, 20> test{};
auto d = ::distance(std::data(test), std::data(test) + std::size(test));
```

> couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Vector’

But if I give it the missing pieces:

```cpp
auto d = distance<intptr_t, intptr_t>(std::data(test), std::data(test) + std::size(test));
```

Is it possible to keep Scalar and Vector as free type parameters and still get type deduction to work properly, or should I require that there are vectors and points posses using aliases that I can pick up on. In that case, point would look like

```cpp
template<class T>
concept point = std::equality_comparable<T> && requires(T p1, T p2)
{
    typename T::vector_type;
    {p1 + v} -> std::same_as<T>;
    {p1 - v} -> std::same_as<T>;
    {p1 += v} -> std::same_as<T&>;
    {p1 -= v} -> std::same_as<T&>;
    {p1 - p2} -> std::same_as<T::vector_type>;
};
```

While this works, the vector `T` must be designed to work with this concept. I really like the idea of affine spaces that works with `std::chrono`:

```cpp
static_assert(point<std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point, std::chrono::steady_clock::duration, long>);
```

Comment: I'm unsure why it is that your concepts repeat information. I mean, a "vector" is a vector over some "scalar" type, right? So any particular "vector" must know what scalar type it is. So why is your "vector" concept also a concept over a particular "scalar?" What is supposed to happen if the "vector"'s scalar type is different from the `ScalarType` parameter you pass into the `vector` concept?

Comment: Notice that subtracting two similar points results in a vector (within that space). Subtracting time_points give a 1d vector (duration), which in this case uses the scalar of type long. For chrono, the scalar type is rep. Pointers are actually also pointy, with vector type intptr_t, and intptr_t is the scalar. But a pointer has no type aliases, and intptr_t doesn't either, so the solution does not generalize.

Comment: Complex numbers are a vector space over themselves and, separately, over reals (and, separately, over rationals and over algebraics and probably some more). Now if you say "let's take vector space C" I will interrupt you and ask "a vector space over what field?" This is exactly what happens with your code.

Comment: @user877329: "*But a pointer has no type aliases*" That's why traits classes were invented.

Answer (score 0):

Concepts do not (directly) interact with template argument deduction. Deduction happens, and arguments are applied to the available templates. Concepts constrain the set of available templates, such that any particular template is either available or not. A concept cannot inform which type deduction comes up with.

So if you want concepts to have those parameters (for some reason), any template constrained on those concepts will have to provide them. And therefore, if deduction cannot otherwise deduce them, those arguments will have to be explicitly provided by the caller of the function.

Comment: So what would be a better solution?

Comment: You want something that is both confused and contradictory. You want the concept to separate notions that are in fact linked (a "vector" type and the type it is a vector over), but you also want the user to not *have to* separate those notions when they use APIs. You cannot have both, and one of these doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

By applying *The fundamental theorem of software engineering*, the problem can be solved by introducing an additional abstraction `vector_space`:

```cpp
template<class T>
concept vector_space = vector<typename T::vector_type, typename T::scalar_type>;

template<class T>
concept affine_space = vector_space<T>
    && point<typename T::point_type, typename T::vector_type, typename T::scalar_type>;
```

Now:

```cpp
struct writable_address_space
{
    using vector_type = intptr_t;
    using scalar_type = intptr_t;
    using point_type = std::byte*;
};

static_assert(affine_space<writable_address_space>);
```